# where can I find a Visual studio 2008 project build file for MPFR? or how to create such build file myself?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mpfr

I a new C++ user and have only Visual studio 2008 installed.
It seems from this link:
 [Brian Gladman's Home Page](http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/computing/gmp4win.php)

There is already "Visual Studio 2010 project build files for building MPFR", which is only for VC2010 and my VS cannot open it.
[mpfr.svn.build.vc10.zip](http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/computing/mpfr.svn.build.vc10.zip)

My questions are:
1) where can I find a version for VS2008?
2) or how can I produce it myself since there are already new updates of mpfr? [project files for mpfr](https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/?group_id=136)

thank you!

######### Problem Solved

Solution: download this pre-compiled mpfr and config VC complier will be OK!
[mpfr_mpir_x86_x64_msvc2010.zip](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1svLer)

Comment: I didnot build the source code myself, but downloaded a precompiled mpfr (vc10 versions available) and solved the problem.

Comment: I noticed the original link of these precompiled files has been dead. So I share my own backup for any others' reference here:

Comment: Please put a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73852387/941531), just  wrote it now, it describes in very details 3 ways of compiling GMP and MPIR under Windows VisualStudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the pre-compiled mpfr library binary by VC++2010 works for both VC++2008 and VC++2010 compliers; the precompiled mpfr library binaries can be found here( link from the original author is now dead; please use this link instead): 
[mpfr_mpir_x86_x64_msvc2010.zip](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1svLer)

(it seems the original author's website now works again: please visit here: [Brian Gladman's guidelines on MPIR & MPFR installation](http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/computing/gmp4win.php) for more detailed information.)

The configuration details of VC++ compliers are similar to those for mpir library as in this link:
[How to Install and Run GMP on Windows Using MPIR](http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-to-install-and-run-gmp-on-windows-using-mpir/)

Windows users are highly recommended to take a look at Pavel's website here:
[Pavel Holoborodko](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/mpfr/) who is the author of the C++ wrapper:
[mpfrc++-3.5.6.zip](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=4)