# How to use opensource C library in Visual C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013, websocket, libwebsockets

I was trying to use a c library libwebsockets(https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets) for my c++ program.
I followed the manual and it creates a visual studio solution and it works.

Since I am not used to develop a program on a windows 7 visual studio environment, I am not sure how library works. It looks like solution contains some test codes and core libraries.

In a windows7 environment, what is the best way to develop a C++ project using this this C library?

I am considering two ways which are:

1. Add the c projects on the c++ project
2. Add the c++ project on the c projects

Comment: You create your project and link the library into it as any other library. In the same solution or not, depending on how you want to do it.

Comment: How do I link the library to a current project? Should I add all library project folders in my solution?

Comment: Have you got a .lib file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two different Projects: One for the C lib and the other for your C++ Code. Then build the C Code into a *.lib File and add it to your C++ Project using this Answer: [How to include libraries in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058864/how-to-include-libraries-in-visual-studio-2012)

You can add both Projects into one Solution so they are easily accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) utility to create VS project files out of make files.