# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 fatal error LNK1169

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, fatal-error

I am running a very simple test program and I have been running into problems mostly with setting up the OpenCV library with Visual Studio. I am not sure why visual studio can't run this file.

Here is the code (very simple)

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>

int main(){
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:/MyOpenCV/Images/MyPic.png");
cvNamedWindow("MyOpenCV");
cvShowImage("MyOpenCV", img);
cvWaitKey(0);
cvDestroyWindow("MyOpenCV");
cvReleaseImage(&img);
return 0;
```

This is the error I get:

> C:\Users\Matthew\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\7.8.15\x64\Release\7.8.15.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *side note*: your project is called "7.8.15" ? oh...

Comment: Have you added the OpenCV libraries to the additional dependencies of the configuration?

Comment: You need to provide more details. The error message is incomplete.

Comment: 1>------ Build started: Project: 7.8.15, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>  Upload Video.cpp
This is what I got right above the error message if that's what you mean @Phil

Comment: @Brett I added the OpenCV directories to this project.

Comment: @MatthewPurri Yes but did you add the libraries? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20059167/2593738