# Adding references in vs 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

How do I do that?

I want to add a reference in a c++ project.

I tried to do this with a msdn guide, but the instructions werent matched
with the possibilities on my VS.

Pics added

[reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC3Su.png)

[reference 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdW27.png)

Comment: Usually I just use `&`.

Comment: what kind of reference are you talking about?

Comment: i built a lib. file, and i want to use it in my program @Nandu

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058864/how-to-include-libraries-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: thank u very much! @Nandu. I think itll work