# NetCDF Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, netcdf

i'm trying to work with `netCDF4.4.0-NC4-64.exe`, I'm develop C++ MFC application on Visual Studio 2013 Debug mode.
I did exactly like the following answer:
[Visual Studio - adding netCDF library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331969/visual-studio-adding-netcdf-library)

I'm trying to run simple code:

```
#include <netcdf.h>
...
void MyMethod()
{
   const char *ver = nc_inq_libvers();
}
```

But when i tried to compile application on `Release` (32bit) i got:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nc_inq_libvers
```

And on `Debug` mode:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _nc_inq_libvers referenced in function...
```

And on 64bit Release/Debug:

```
error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

What is the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing 32- and 64-bits file versions. Try installing netcdf 3netCDF4.4.0-NC4-64.exe,