# How can I use the C++ shlwapi library in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, linker

My program uses the [`PathFileExistsW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathfileexistsw) function from `shlwapi.h`:

```
#include <shlwapi.h>

int main() {
    LPCWSTR folderName = L"";
    PathFileExistsW(folderName);
}
```

If I compile it, I get the following linker error. How to solve it.?

```
Example.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PathFileExistsW
    referenced in function main
```

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058864/how-to-include-libraries-in-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: @meJustAndrew This is a headache. I can't find where to download the file from windows, so maybe I don't have to do that. I got to download it from an X website. I make a new line in library directories but I can't set the dll, because it doesn't appear on the screen. Do you have any idea of what should I do to make this shlwapi library to work?

Comment: I SOLVED THE PROBLEM. THE PROBLEM WAS THAT I WAS USING AN IF. YOU CAN'T USE IF'S WITH BOOL TYPES. There is not need to adding any weird extra configuration.

Comment: Update: You also need to write 
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib"). But if I kept using the if I kept having the same error no matter if wrote the pragma. I don't even know why are these errors so tricky

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: The pragma directive is **one** way to pass settings to the linker. How to specify linker settings using your IDE is explained in your IDE's manual.

Comment: @IInspectable I hate microsofts' articles. I've tried reading a couple of them no one resolved my problems, specially because at some point they are not very precise as some other SO answers I've seen (I made a new project and worked, the problem was that I deleted some files by "accident"). I don't know where to find a manual for VS and if I found one I wouldn't know how to look for what I was looking for, since I didn't know what did linker mean until yesterday (I still don't understand if fully). PS: Please stop the hate or I'm going to get banned from asking at SO longer

Comment: From [PathFileExists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584.aspx): *"Library: Shlwapi.lib"*. Documentation for the linker and how your IDE can be used to set up your project: [.Lib Files as Linker Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx).

Answer (score 11):

Add shlwapi.lib to your dependency list:

Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

Answer (score 4):

Adding a [`comment lib`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp#lib) pragma anywhere in the .cpp solves the linker error:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")
```

Comment: Actually, you always want to compare to `FALSE`, since a false condition is always 0 (and `FALSE` is a constant 0). A true condition can be *any* non-zero value, and may not necessarily be `TRUE` (which is a constant 1). The original code that you say is "wrong" was actually fine and is idiomatic C++.

Comment: It doesn't matter **where** you put the linker directive. It is a linker setting after all, an the compiler will emit it into the object code, irrespective of where it sees it.

Comment: There is *NO DIFFERENCE* between using `!` vs `== FALSE` for a `BOOL` value. Whichever one you use has *NO EFFECT* whatsoever on the linker at all. `!` correctly interprets a zero as false and a non-zero as true. The function is clearly documented as returning "*TRUE if the file exists; otherwise, FALSE*". There is no other value returned. `!` works just fine on all APIs that return a `BOOL`.

Comment: Well, then it is very strange that with only changing that line I could build the code

Comment: @Cody Gray: I know that, but I felt like if for some reason a number different than 1 (like a negative) was returned it shouldn't be treated as true. Anyways, it's the first time I use the BOOL type. If the code I said was wrong is actually good, then I'm just more confused. Changing that line got rid off the linking error. I had the pragma line before and kept having the error. Now I have another trouble with FindFirstFile returning always INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.

Comment: I tested it again and it seems you are right, there is no difference. (Still strange why didn't it work!)

Comment: Remy is actually correct here. `PathFileExists` is specifically documented as either returning TRUE or FALSE. That is not the typical case, though. Generally when you see a Windows API function that returns a BOOL, it returns FALSE if it fails, or non-zero if it succeeds. That non-zero *might* be TRUE, but it might not be. You cannot assume that failure is anything else but FALSE. That's why you compare to FALSE, or just use the logical negation operator, as suggested. Perhaps your first attempt received a compiler *warning*, something about coercing an integer to a boolean?

Comment: MSVC issues a warning in these cases, calling it something like a "performance warning". This is not an error, just a warning, but it looks kind of scary if you don't know what's up. Google it for more information (a good strategy with errors/warnings anyway). Their suggested workaround is to compare explicitly against FALSE. The customary pattern is: `if (WinAPIFunction(...) != FALSE)  { // it worked }`. The exact same object code is generated in both cases, so it's basically a stupid warning.

Comment: There's no need to add the `== FALSE` in the code. With the `!` operator works fine (at least in VS2013). Not sure what madness is going on in your code :)

Comment: It is better to add shlwapi.lib to your dependency list than to add a #pragma.

Comment: @Carlos I also encounter the same issue, only adding #pragma can successfully build. Then I found that the build error is actually from another test project, not the project I added lib dependency. FYI.

Comment: Somehow this wasn't enough in my case, had to manually add it to the linker dependencies...

Answer (score 0):

First you need to [add VC++ directories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855621.aspx)
Then you need to set linker input.