# C++ MEX file external Linkage error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include "mex.h"

#include "matrix.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;



inline int getAddressOffset(int32_t u, int32_t v, int32_t height) {
return u*height + v;
}

// get response from integral image
inline double getSumFromIntegralImage(double *img_integral, int32_t height, 
int32_t u1, int32_t u2, int32_t v1, int32_t v2) {
double          sum = *(img_integral + getAddressOffset(u2, v2, height));
if (u1>0)       sum -= *(img_integral + getAddressOffset(u1 - 1, v2, 
height));
if (v1>0)       sum -= *(img_integral + getAddressOffset(u2, v1 - 1, 
height));
if (v1>0 && u1>0) sum += *(img_integral + getAddressOffset(u1 - 1, v1 - 1, 
height));
return sum;
}

// create integral image
void createIntegralImage(double *I, double *I_integral, const uint32_t *dims) 
{

// extract image width and height and number of disparities
const int width = dims[1];
const int height = dims[0];

double *S = (double*)calloc(height*width, sizeof(double));

int32_t addr_u_v;
int32_t addr_u1_v;
int32_t addr_u_v1;

// for all pixels do
for (int u = 0; u<width; u++) {
    for (int v = 0; v<height; v++) {

        addr_u_v = getAddressOffset(u, v, height);

        // S(v,u) = I(v,u);
        if (u == 0) {
            *(S + addr_u_v) = *(I + addr_u_v);

            // S(v,u) = S(v,u-1) + I(v,u);
        }
        else {
            addr_u1_v = getAddressOffset(u - 1, v, height);
            *(S + addr_u_v) = *(S + addr_u1_v) + *(I + addr_u_v);
        }

        // I_integral(v,u) = S(v,u);
        if (v == 0) {
            *(I_integral + addr_u_v) = *(S + addr_u_v);

            // I_integral(v,u) = I_integral(v-1,u) + S(v,u);
        }
        else {
            addr_u_v1 = getAddressOffset(u, v - 1, height);
            *(I_integral + addr_u_v) = *(I_integral + addr_u_v1) + *(S + 
  addr_u_v);
        }
    }
    }
  free(S);
   }

  void boxFilter(double *img, double *box, const uint32_t *dims, int32_t 
  radius) {

  const int width = dims[1];
  const int height = dims[0];

  double *img_integral = (double*)calloc(width*height, sizeof(double));

  createIntegralImage(img, img_integral, dims);

  // for all pixels do
   for (int32_t u = 0; u<width; u++) {
    for (int32_t v = 0; v<height; v++) {
        int32_t u1 = std::max(u - radius, 0);
        int32_t u2 = std::min(u + radius, width - 1);
        int32_t v1 = std::max(v - radius, 0);
        int32_t v2 = std::min(v + radius, height - 1);
        double sum = getSumFromIntegralImage(img_integral, height, u1, u2, 
       v1, v2);
        *(box + getAddressOffset(u, v, height)) = sum / (double)((u2 - u1 + 
         1)*(v2 - v1 + 1));
        }
    }

   free(img_integral);
   }

  void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray 
   *prhs[]) {

// check for proper number of arguments
if (nrhs != 2)
    mexErrMsgTxt("2 inputs required (img,radius).");
if (nlhs != 1)
    mexErrMsgTxt("One output required (box).");

// check for proper argument types and sizes
if (!mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) || mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[0]) != 2)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Input img must be a double matrix.");
if (!mxIsDouble(prhs[1]) || mxGetN(prhs[1])*mxGetM(prhs[1]) != 1)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Input radius must be a double scalar.");

// get pointers
double* img = (double*)mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
const uint32_t *dims = mxGetDimensions(prhs[0]);
int32_t  radius = *((double*)mxGetPr(prhs[1]));

// create output
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(2, dims, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
double* box = (double*)mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

// do computation
boxFilter(img, box, dims, radius);
}
```

I'm getting this following errors:

> Error    5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mxIsDouble referenced in function _mexFunction   C:\Users\Arvind\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test1\box.obj test1
>
> Error    6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mxGetPr referenced in function _mexFunction  C:\Users\Arvind\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test1\box.obj test1
>
> Error    2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mxGetNumberOfDimensions_730 referenced in function _mexFunction  C:\Users\Arvind\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test1\box.obj test1
>
> Error    7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mxGetN referenced in function _mexFunction   C:\Users\Arvind\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test1\box.obj test1
>
> Error    4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mxGetM referenced in function _mexFunction   C:\Users\Arvind\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test1\box.obj test1
>
> Error    3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mxGetDimensions_730 referenced in function _mexFunction  C:\Users\Arvind\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test1\box.obj test1
>
> Error    8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mxCreateNumericArray_730 referenced in function _mexFunction C:\Users\Arvind\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test1\box.obj test1
>
> Error    9   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mexErrMsgTxt referenced in function _mexFunction C:\Users\Arvind\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test1\box.obj test1
>
> Error    10  error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Arvind\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test1\Debug\test1.exe test1

Comment: Please do format your code a lot better.

Comment: How do you compile it?

Comment: Looks like (at least 1) missing library. You have to add the library (.lib) in the property sheets. Have a look at [SO: How to include libraries in Visual Studio 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058864/how-to-include-libraries-in-visual-studio-2012) if you want to know how to do it. (It's similar in other versions of VS.) Remark: Some projects provide property files (.vcxproj or .props) which might be used instead: [A guide to .vcxproj and .props file structure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/05/14/a-guide-to-vcxproj-and-props-file-structure/)